# hi, need help in cleaning excel data or reject the wrong cells atleast

Tags: excel, filtering

I am collecting a specific data through sms from 200 members daily, converting into excel, using this data for analysis. Sms format is 5 numbers (4-6 digits each, not fixed length) separated by single space. Few entries sent to me contains text, dots, etc. How to clean this data in excel? sms like '172625 7665 83737 76 5678' is correct but 176253.653 m876 nil 8733 is not correct..? atleast a way out to reject the cells with invalid data..

Comment: When you put your data in excel, is it in a single column?

Comment: Is the data collected in a .txt or .csv file before moving it to excel?

Comment: I.e. you need to strip from the string all characters that are not number or space?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(1*SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")),A1,"invalid")
```